# Как корректно запустить приложение Qt в полноэкранном режиме? Странное поведение метода showFullScreen()

Tags: c++, qt

Я делаю проект на `Qt 4.8/C++`До сегодняшнего дня я пользовался методом `resize()`для изменения размеров главного окна и методом `show()` для  показа этого окна соответственно, получалось обычное окно со системным оформлением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил развернуть окошко при запуске приложения на весь экран, используя метод `showFullScreen()`, и `Qt` слишком буквально меня понял. Вот что вышло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, окно действительно растянулось на весь экран, закрыв даже панель задач `windows`, крестик и рамки "ушли" за границу монитора, поэтому пришлось убивать процесс через диспетчер задач. Собственно код стандартный, изменил только `w.show()` на `w.showFullScreen()`.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Как это исправить? Почему этот метод ведет себя так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь showMaximized()

Answer (score 5):

> Почему этот метод ведет себя так?

Потому что полноэкранный режим и режим "развернуть во весь экран" — разные режимы. Первый используется, например, играми, чтобы погрузить пользователя в виртуальный мир. А второй, которого ожидал автор (и который активируется методом `QWidget::showMaximized()`) — это обычный результат нажатия кнопки "Развернуть" в заголовке окна.

> крестик и рамки "ушли" за границу монитора

Нет, они не ушли за границу монитора: их попросту нет вообще в полноэкранном режиме.

> пришлось убивать процесс через диспетчер задач

В этом не было необходимости: обычная комбинация <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> справилась бы с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Еще Alt+пробел может помочь. Даже окно можно так двигать без мышки.